# Unable to wget for ipv6

Tags: linux, wget, ipv6

I tried wget using the following command

```
wget -6  https://[fe80::]
```

But it displayed the following error

> Connecting to [fe80::]:80... failed: Invalid argument.

Comment: Did you actually use `[fe80::]`, or did you use a valid IPv6 address?

Answer (score 3):

An IPv6 address that starts with `fe80:` is a link-local address and needs a scope identifier (basically, a network interface name) added to it, e.g. if your network interface is `eno1` and the IPv6 address is `fe80::1`, then the command should be:

```
wget -6 https://[fe80::1%eno1]/
```

[There is also a bug in wget that might apply.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wget/+bug/1566930)

Also possibly related: [wget and cURL an explicit IPv6 Address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356451/wget-and-curl-an-explicit-ipv6-address)

Comment: While some write this up as a "bug" it's such a common one, some would argue that using link-local addresses for higher level protocols should be discouraged.  There are very many programs which are not aware of the link syntax or semantics.

Comment: Some would argue that using addresses instead of host names should be discouraged, for any type of addresses. Using mDNS to map to link-local addresses works fine.

Comment: @PhilipCouling they don't have to be aware. They should use standard parsing interfaces, like `getaddrinfo(3)`. And why, pray, should people be discouraged from using *valid* addresses in their protocols?

Comment: @mosvy yes they are valid, but use with higher level protocols frequently fails the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) leading to this type of question and leading to "bugs".  For example adding an Ethernet adaptor wouldn't usually change unrelated target IP addresses. But with link-local addresses it might change `eth0` to `eth1` and thus change an unrelated address.  And wget [does use](https://github.com/jay/wget/blob/099d8ee3da3a6eea5635581ae517035165f400a5/src/host.c#L326) `getaddrinfo`.  The problem is more subtle than that.

Comment: @PhilipCouling How subtle it is? It's the very point of link-local addresses that they're, somethink like, huh, link-local and you should tell what link they should be used on ;-) I've already promised, but now, it's for good, I'll stop trying to pick apart your nonsense claims.

Comment: @mosvy You haven't picked apart my claims at all, I haven't said link-local addresses are hard to understand, I've said they have surprising semantics which lead to bugs.  You are plain wrong to suggest that use of the standard API will cover over the surprising behaviour. It doesn't.  For (yet another) example, a HTTP server can issue a `301` redirect to bounce a client to a different IP address.  But the server doesn't know the client's interface specification so cannot bounce to a link local address.  It would only work if the client is aware that it needs to manually specify an interface.

Comment: @mosvy Most software isn't written to bind to a specific interface.  Countless protocols are written which allow machines to share IP addresses (eg bit torrent).  If the software doesn't explicitly specify an interface, it cannot make use of a link-local address sent by another host.  Low level protocols are typically implemented to be aware of this, higher level protocols (http, torrent...) aren't.  This isn't hard to understand it's just supprising.